# Circular Path Animation not working with Pulsating Movement

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

I'm trying to achieve a kind of pulsating moon effect with canvas in HTML5. I have the pulsating effect, but my requestAnimation function does not seem to be updating the frame along the circular path that I have defined. Here's the javascript.

```
window.requestAnimFrame = function() {
return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame 
||
window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame
|| window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
  function(a) {
   window.setTimeout(a, 1E3 / 60)
  }
}();


var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');       
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

 function Ball(radius, color) {
  if (radius === undefined) {
   radius = 40;
   }
  if (color === undefined) {
  color = "#ff0000";
   }

  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
  this.radius = radius;
  this.rotation = 0;
  this.scaleX = 1;
  this.scaleY = 1;
  this.lineWidth = 1;
  }

  Ball.prototype.draw = function(context) {
  context.save();
  context.translate(this.x, this.y);
  context.rotate(this.rotation);
  context.scale(this.scaleX, this.scaleY);
  context.lineWidth = this.lineWidth;
  context.fillStyle = "#e50000";
  context.beginPath();
  //x, y, radius, start_angle, end_angle, anti-clockwise
  context.arc(0, 0, this.radius, 0, (Math.PI * 2), true);
  context.closePath();
  context.fill();
 if (this.lineWidth > 0) {
  context.stroke();
  }
  context.restore();
  };

  window.onload = function() {    
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
        context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
        ball = new Ball(),
        angle = 0,
        centerScale = 1,
        range = 0.5,
        speed = 0.02,
 
pathX = canvas.width / 2,
pathY = canvas.height / 2,
pathRadius = 150,
pathAngle = 0;
ball.x = Math.cos(pathAngle) * pathRadius + pathX;
ball.y = Math.sin(pathAngle) * pathRadius + pathY;  

   (function drawFrame() {      
   window.requestAnimationFrame(drawFrame, canvas);      
   context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);      
  ball.scaleX = ball.scaleY = centerScale + Math.sin(angle) * range;  
  angle += speed;    
  pathAngle += speed;
  ball.draw(context);    
  }());  
};
```

Comment: Here is a link to the CodePen : http://codepen.io/WriterState/pen/EyKPpq?editors=0110

Answer (score 0):

You're rotating a circle around it's own centerpoint so it's not orbiting relative to it's centerpoint.

```
// offset the circles rotation by 100px off its centerpoint
context.arc(100, 0, this.radius, 0, (Math.PI * 2), true);
```

**Example code ad a demo:**

```js
window.requestAnimFrame = function() {
return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame 
||
window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame
|| window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
  function(a) {
   window.setTimeout(a, 1E3 / 60)
  }
}();


var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');       
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

 function Ball(radius, color) {
  if (radius === undefined) {
   radius = 40;
   }
  if (color === undefined) {
  color = "#ff0000";
   }

  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
  this.radius = radius;
  this.rotation = 0;
  this.scaleX = 1;
  this.scaleY = 1;
  this.lineWidth = 1;
  }

  Ball.prototype.draw = function(context) {
  context.save();
  context.translate(this.x, this.y);
  context.rotate(this.rotation);
  context.scale(this.scaleX, this.scaleY);
  context.lineWidth = this.lineWidth;
  context.fillStyle = "#e50000";
  context.beginPath();
  //x, y, radius, start_angle, end_angle, anti-clockwise
  context.arc(50, 0, this.radius, 0, (Math.PI * 2), true);
  context.closePath();
  context.fill();
 if (this.lineWidth > 0) {
  context.stroke();
  }
  context.restore();
  };

  window.onload = function() {    
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
        context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
        ball = new Ball(),
        angle = 0,
        centerScale = 1,
        range = 0.5,
        speed = 0.02,
 
        pathX = canvas.width / 2,
        pathY = canvas.height / 2,
        pathRadius = 50,
        pathAngle = 0;
        ball.x = canvas.width/2;  // Math.cos(pathAngle) * pathRadius + pathX;
        ball.y = canvas.height/2; //Math.sin(pathAngle) * pathRadius + pathY;  

   (function drawFrame() {      
   window.requestAnimationFrame(drawFrame, canvas);      
   context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);      
  ball.scaleX = ball.scaleY = centerScale + Math.sin(angle) * range;  
  angle += speed;    
  pathAngle += speed;
  ball.rotation+=Math.PI/180;
  ball.draw(context);    
  }());  
};
```

```css
body{ background-color:white; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. 

The orbit path is defined by     
pathX = canvas.width / 2,
pathY = canvas.height / 2,
pathRadius = 150,
pathAngle = 0;

Comment: You are translating to the circle's centerpoint. Then you are rotating the canvas around that point. But you are not moving the circle outward from it's centerpoint (pathRadius is not applied) so your circle is really spinning like a record around itself. You also need to increment rotation each frame. I've added example code and a demo to my answer. Cheers!